# Performing minmax for Pandas rows using a list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe of the following format, groupedby the group column.

```
df

      SubGroup  Income(SubGroup)  Income(Group)
Group 
E2     E21      60899.298717      52000.0
       E22      62970.477999      52000.0
       E23      45312.178300      52000.0
E3     E31      29906.997457      44000.0
       E32      58582.304769      44000.0
```

I would like to perform a minmax on incomes of the same group which has a range of -25% and +25% of the income for its group.

When performing the groupby, I could set these range values:

```
df

      SubGroup  Income(SubGroup)  Income(Group) Lower    Upper
Group 
E2     E21      60899.298717      52000.0       39000.0  65000.0
       E22      62970.477999      52000.0       39000.0  65000.0
       E23      45312.178300      52000.0       39000.0  65000.0
E3     E31      29906.997457      44000.0       33000.0  55000.0
       E32      58582.304769      44000.0       33000.0  55000.0
```

I know I can do something vaguely like this:

```
data = df['Income(Group)'].values()
data = np.asarray(data)
np.interp(data, (data.min(), data.max()), (df['Lower'], df['Upper']))
```

to achieve the minmax for the entire column, but how can I package this into a list comprehension to ensure this only takes place on individual rows with their respective Income(SubGroup) and Lower and Upper bound figures?

Thanks!

Comment: why not use assign?

Comment: It's not clear to me how I would do that